# What happens if I accidentally delete a key in Cloud KMS?

Tags: google-cloud-kms

I accidentally destroyed key material for a key version that I was using in Cloud KMS. Is there any way I can recover the data encrypted with that key version?

Answer (score 3):

Key material purposely has a [configurable *Scheduled for destruction state* duration](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/create-key#soft_delete) or delay for destruction. If it's still within that period, use **restore** to get back the key material for that key version. Note that this requires an Owner or a Cloud KMS Admin IAM role.

If it's been longer than the duration configured at creation time, that key material is gone. Unfortunately, that means that any data encrypted with that key is practically irrecoverable.

**NOTE:** As of 1-Feb-2024, the *default* duration of the *Scheduled for destruction state* is **30 days**. (Before this date the *default* was 24 hours.)

To restore a key version using gcloud, run:

```
gcloud beta kms cryptokeys versions restore $VERSION_NUMBER \
    --location LOCATION \
    --keyring KEYRING_NAME \
    --cryptokey CRYPTOKEY_NAME
```